# Expectation inequality

Tags: inequality, expected-value

How can I prove that
$$
\mathbb{E} [X^2] \geq \mathbb{E} [|X|]^2
$$
This resembles the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality a lot but I'm unable to prove it with the usual method (i.e. when there are two random variables and you choose to set $f(\alpha)=(X-\alpha Y)^2$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a special case of Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Jensen's inequality we know that, whenever f is a convex function and X is a random variable we have:
$$ E(f(X)) \geq f(E(X))$$.

In this context $f(X) = X^2$, which is a convex function and hence we are done.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if considering the absolute value of the R.V. doesn't change things a little bit...

Comment: @james42 $\lvert X\rvert^2 = X^2$

Comment: Abby and @Calculon $E[|X|]^2 = E[X]^2$?

Comment: @BCLC Jensen: $E[\lvert X\rvert^2] \geq E[\lvert X\rvert]^2$. The convex function underneath is $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert^2$.

Comment: @Calculon What do you mean? How do you know that that inequality you stated is true? I plugged in $f(X) = |X|^2$ into inequality Abby said, but I don't see how that proves what OP wants

Comment: @BCLC It is Jensen's equality. Instead of $X$ consider $\lvert X \rvert $ as the random variable.

Comment: @Calculon Good job on deleting that comment :))

Comment: @BCLC I pressed enter by mistake instead of apostrophe.

Comment: @Calculon Ah nice, edit Abby's answer so that I can upvote please?

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $t\in(0,1)$, we have 
\begin{align}
(ta^2+(1-t)b^2) - (ta+(1-t)b)^2  &= ta^2 + (1-t)b^2 -t^2a^2 -2t(1-t)ab -(1-t)^2b^2\\
&= t(1-t)a^2 -2t(1-t)ab + t(1-t)b^2\\
&= t(1-t)(a-b)^2\\
&>0,
\end{align}
so $x\mapsto x^2$ is a convex function. It follows from Jensen's inequality that $$\mathbb E[X^2]\geqslant \mathbb E[X]^2 $$ and $$\mathbb E[X^2]=\mathbb E[(-X)^2]\geqslant \mathbb E[-X]^2, $$ and so $$\mathbb E[X^2]\geqslant \mathbb E[|X|]^2. $$

Answer (score 0):

$Var(|X|) = E[|X|^2] - E[|X|]^2 \geq 0 $ and this implies the result